# Array Index Out OfBounds Help (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception

This Java program does a simple computation and it is suppose to output the numerical value of `123+1`

> (The output should be 124.) (Ignore the last "+" string.)

I got an error inside the if statement:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

I did a printout for `arrayz[i-1]` and `arrayz[i+1]` and it seems to printout 123 and 1 receptively, which is correct. So, I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
        String math = "123+1+";
        String arrayz[]={"123","+","1","+"};
        double total =0.0;

        int i=0;
        while(i<=(math.length()-1))        //don't bother with the last char
        {       i++;
            if(arrayz[i].equals("+"))
            {
                total = Double.parseDouble((String)arrayz[i-1]) + Double.parseDouble((String)arrayz[i+1]);

            }

        }

        System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: Increment i at the end of the loop, not the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the index `i` with the array `arrayz`, you must use `arrayz.length` instead of `math.length()`

**Edit**

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String math = "123+1+";
    String arrayz[] = { "123", "+", "1", "+" };
    double total = 0.0;

    int i = 0;

    // arrayz.length - 2 -> because you are accessing "arrayz[i + 1]", 
    // arrayz.length - 1 would be OK if the maximum index you were using were "arrayz[i] "
    while (i <= (arrayz.length - 2)) //don't bother with the last char
    {           
        if (arrayz[i].equals("+")) {
            total = Double.parseDouble((String) arrayz[i - 1]) + Double.parseDouble((String) arrayz[i + 1]);
        }
        i++; // Increment at the end of the loop
    }

    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Comment: Try using `length` without `()`

Comment: No way! What's the error? You may increment (i++) after all the computations, in other words, at the end of the loop. You could use a for loop to avoid this.

Comment: it works when I do while(i<=(arrayz.length-3)) but it doesn't look efficient.

Comment: What happen is that you are accessing with the index `i+1`, you must correct this too.

Comment: yup, I put the i++ after the if statement. I'm still getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44037/discussion-between-christian-and-phumb)

Answer (score 3):

```
   while(i<=(math.length()-1))
```

math length is 6  and and in side loop your array length is 4

You might want to write

```
 while(i<=(arrayz.length-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over the string `math`, at the same time accessing elements of `arrayz` inside your loop, and thinking that they have the same elements and the same length.
What I suggest you, is to use instead of math String (you can omit it in this case but I assume you can't in general for some criteria), you can use an array of type String, so that 123 in your example would be the first element `arrayz[0]`.